# What is Gandalf's Westron name, and why does he sign with a "G" rune?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, gandalf, tolkien-languages

Gandalf signs his letter to the bartender in Bree with a "G" rune:

[image: G Rune]

But "Gandalf" is the English rendition of what's presumably meant to be Westron in-universe. What then is Gandalf's real Westron name, and does it also start with "G"?

Comment: That rune isn't actually a G. It's the Gandalfian symbol for hope.

Comment: Names aren't necessarily changed when "translated" to another language. Why can't his name be Gandalf on Westron and English both? Similarly, the rune isn't Westron but Cirth. And then there was also this dude who engraved something on some ring in Black Speech, but using Tengwar runes.

Comment: @Amarth Maybe it could be the same, but seeing how different the Westron is for the names we do know, I would be rather surprised.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### We don't know

[You can find a list of all known words from Westron here.](https://eldamo.org/content/language-pages/lang-wes.html) Including both the present-day Westron that the hobbits use and the archaic version that the Rohirrim use, there are only 53 known names. Gandalf is not one of them.

However, we can assume that Gandalf's westron name does in fact begin with a G sound. The same can be said of the Westron word for "garden".

> 'For you little gardener and lover of trees,' she said to Sam, 'I have only a small gift.' She put into his hand a little box of plain grey wood, unadorned save for a single silver rune upon the lid. **'Here is set G for Galadriel,' she said; 'but also it may stand for garden in your tongue.** In this box there is earth from my orchard, and such blessing as Galadriel has still to bestow is upon it.
> <sub>The Lord of the Rings - Book II - Chapter 8 - "Farewell to Lórien"</sub>

For further reading about the possible implications of Westron garden starting with a 'G', see "There are fairies at the bottom of our Garden" by Carl Hostetter and Patrick Wynne in *Vinyar Tengwar* issue #32. It's very speculative, but they analyze the known Westron roots that begin with a 'G' and some of that can probably be applied here as well.

Comment: ...Was Galadriel just re-gifting?  "Here, someone gave me this monogrammed box at our wedding several centuries ago.  I filled it with some dirt so you can have it.  Enjoy!"

Comment: Being acquainted with the insane level of detail in the meta-translating that Tolkien worked on (Ban, Maura, Kalimac = Sam, Frodo, Meriadoc etc.), it is funny that *every time* I have read the quoted passage while reading the book, I have virtually the same narrative in my head which as contained in the question and this answer.

Comment: @Yorik: I just assumed the letters got translated by determining the name, translating the name, and putting the appropriate letter.

Comment: Or perhaps it's yet another "translation". If there's English in runes on the Tomb of Balin (presumably representing Westron), why can't the <G> also be a "representation"?